# During the production of antiprotons with an iridium target, does the target have to be replaced?

Tags: antimatter

I mean, to keep producing the same amount of antiprotons for every proton beam.

If so, what's the maximum total amount of antiprotons that can be produced (not trapped) with a target with a certain size/mass?

I read that in Fermilab for each 200,000 protons hitting, one antiproton is produced (0.0005%). But I don't know the dimensions and material of the target they use.

I also read that in CERN, 26 GeV/c (not sure what speed is that) proton beams hit an iridium fixed target of 3 mm diameter, 55 mm length. I think in this case they use 1.5e13 proton beams to produce 5e7 antiprotons (0.0003%).